# How to Convert DOM document object to xml applying utf-8 charset encoding

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8

I have a requirement to convert a DOM document object to xml and ensure the content of the xml is in utf-8 charset. 
My code looks like below but it is not achieving the intended result and in the xml generated I can see that the characters are not getting encoded.

```
Document doc = (Document)operation.getResult(); //this method is returning the document object
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();    
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();        
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no"); 
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml"); 
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(osw);
transformer.transform(domSource,result);
```

The outputStream got from the above code is provided to a FILE Download component in ADF and here seeing that the generated xml file is not encoded for the special chars tough the header line stating the encoding is getting generated. 
The sample of xml file getting generated is like this.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<PlanObjects>
      <CompPlan BusinessUnit="Vision Operations" OrgId="204" Name="RNNewCompPlan" StartDate="2015-01-01" EndDate="2015-12-31">
         <CompPlansVORow>
            <CompPlanName>RNNewCompPlan</CompPlanName>
            <Description>Using some special chars in desc - ¥ © ¢ </Description>
            <DisplayName>RNNewCompPlan</DisplayName>
         </CompPlansVORow>
   </CompPlan>
</PlanObjects>
```

Was expecting the characters "¥ © ¢ " to have got encoded and display as hex / octet code.
Can someone please suggest what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Your code is ok and generates a XML document encoded in UTF-8. What does *the generated xml file is not encoded for the special chars tough the header line* mean?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please clarify: "My code looks like below but it is not achieving the intended result and in the xml generated I can see that the characters are not getting encoded."

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: this is Java.

Comment: @user2082317: try getting rid of the `OutputStreamWriter` and construct the `StreamResult` using `outputStream` directly. You already told the `Transformer` to output UTF-8, so let it write UTF-8 bytes directly to `outputStream`. The `OutputStreamWriter` is not gaining you anything in this situation, and even the [`StreamResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html) documentation suggests using a stream instead of a `Writer`.

Comment: Have tried using the outputStream directly without OutputStreamWriter but   with no luck.

Comment: Have edited my question providing details of how the generated xml is looking like. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of UTF-8 is incorrect - `¥ © ¢` have been encoded as UTF-8, along with the rest of the file. You can verify that by opening your file in an hex editor and find the sequence: `'c2a5 c2a9 c2a2'`, which will be the UTF-8 encoding of `¥ © ¢`.

AFAIK, you shouldn't use hexadecimal/octal character escape sequences in XML. An XML parser will decode your file without issue.

To test your code works with another parser, use the following python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print ET.tostring(root, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Verified by opening the file in hex editor, that the sequence 'c2a5 c2a9 c2a2' exists. So does this means to say that the encoding to UTF-8 is happening properly with the written code. Then in that case could you please explain what is the best way to test this code.  With what special characters ? Also, If the XML parser is able to parse this file without issue, it will prove that the encoding is happening properly, right ? Any other ways to confirm ?

Comment: Ok, so your file is definately UTF-8. You should be able to open it in a text editor, set with an encoding of UTF-8. There's nothing special about those characters, apart from them being non-ASCII. You can read it with any old XML parser and it will parse.

Comment: I've added some test code to my answer for you to validate a parser outside of Java